# Why doesn't AngularJS initialize with inline <script>?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://codepen.io/krabbypattified/pen/oYxmKz

View above Codepen. The Chrome DevTools console returns Error: [$injector:modulerr]. The same error occurs when script area is commented.

However, when script area is commented and the (identical) JS section is uncommented, Angular works fine with no errors. Why does this happen??

Note: I have a large application and isolated the bug to this phenomenon. I'm using a Prepros server and I'm getting this same annoying $injector error.

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);

app.controller('testController', function($scope){
  $scope.title = "Hello, World!";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain the commenting part in more detail...it really doesn't make sense as written and neither  demo nor code shown  reflect anything to do with it...unless this whole question only relates to how to use codepen

Comment: Thanks David for the nice explanation. However, it turns out in my application, I used <script src=".../angular.js" /> instead of <script src=".."></script>. So forgetting to close the script tag caused the same error!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Codepen adds the code after the HTML, so the script you have initializing Angular won't have access to angular. If you change to this it will work.

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = 
    angular.module('testApp', []).controller('testController', function($scope){
  $scope.title = "Hello, World!";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

  app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Hello, World!";
  });
</script>
```

Your  angularjs library reference is not applied to your code.

Answer (score 0):

In codepen,Attach your script in HTML rather than mentioning in settings window,

**[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/JbXzGK)**

Problem is codepen in HTML window you can have only HTML code,

Check here it works,

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

    app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
      $scope.title = "Hello, World!";
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/L4lyzLTurk8cUGAHYMgz?p=preview)**

Comment: doesn't account for issue OP is questioning though, just points out a different bug in setting up the demo

Comment: @charlietfl i have mentioned in the 2nd part

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood question and it is only about why codepen doesn't work...think so?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes he is trying to execute on code pen without mentioning the script.

Comment: Ok...terrible title for a specific environment problem then